# Knock out $parent hits click event fine, but resulting object's properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the code below, both buttons, trigger the correct click handler. However when the second button is clicked, all properties of that object are undefined! Is $parent the right reference to use here? Is there another way to do this?

```
<a class="btn rc" href="#" data-bind="click: goClick">This items works.</a>
      <div class="criteria" data-bind="with: profileCriteria">
        <a class="btn rc" href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.goClick">This doesn't relaly work</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: It will help a lot to see how your model is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of the `click` handler is the **current** datacontext. So in your first usage `click: goClick` the parameter will be the your main object which is what you expect.

But when you are inside the `data-bind="with: profileCriteria"` the current datacontext is the `profileCriteria` object so that gets passed to your click handler. So KO does not automatically figures out that you need here the `$parent` as the paramater.

On solution is to pass the `$parent` manually to your function (see in the documentation: [Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters section](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)):

```
<a class="btn rc" href="#" 
   data-bind="click: function() { return $parent.goClick($parent); }">
```

Comment: I think you should avoid inline functions like that at all times, check my answer for a way of avoiding it

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approuch and in my opinion more correct is

```
<a class="btn rc" href="#" 
   data-bind="click: $parent.goClick.bind($parent)">
```

What this will result in is that the context of `this` will be the parent, and the argument to the function will be the data context of the item clicked (profileCriteria)